# How to put Image inside FAB

Tags: android, android-imageview, floating-action-button

I am stuck. Can you help me out. I want to put a circular image url inside a I am stuck. Can you help me out. I want to put a circular image url inside a FAB button. But it not setting properly check this image I am getting like this (Screenshot.png). I am using clans fab library for it. But i want it like (FAB.jpg) check the top most fab with image.[image][image]

If possible kindly help me out

Comment: did u get the solution ?Please provide

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Clans/FloatingActionButton` library

Here is way to create menu

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
}

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_style="@style/YourCustomLabelsStyle"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_fab_label="your_label_here"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/my_show_animation"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/my_hide_animation">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Menu item 1" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

here is [library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) link

Comment: I am already using the library what you said. I want the image on FAB. how to do that? Take look at first screen shot first fab with a lady image. I want like that?